# Is Icepick broken?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I've tried some very simple tests with a fragment. But Icepick does not seem to be saving the value of String test in the outState bundle...

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Icicle String test;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Icepick.restoreInstanceState(this,savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
        Log.d(TAG,"restored value of test="+test);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        test="I have a value";
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Icepick.saveInstanceState(this,outState);
        Log.d(TAG, "test="+test);
   }
```

My gradle build looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my31daychallenge.mysleepchallenge"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.1'
    apt 'com.bluelinelabs:logansquare-compiler:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.bluelinelabs:logansquare:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'frankiesardo:icepick:3.0.0'
    provided 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.0.0'
}
```

Note, I tried the latest version of Icepick 3.0.2 and 3.0.3-SNAPSHOT, none of them worked, so I thought to use an earlier version with the same result.

and also:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {url "https://clojars.org/repo/"}
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: are you still seeing this? I'm having the same problem on 3.1.0 of the library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I literally started looking at the IcePick library 5 minutes ago so keep that in mind if this is a stupid answer :)

As of this commit https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick/commit/f60b4b9c0307be208178381661ee13b958eda531
it looks like @State should be used instead of @Icicle. Does this solve your issue?

Answer (score 7):

In your build.gradle file, for this line `provided 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.0.0'` change `provided` to `apt`. That should do the trick.

Source: https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick/issues/56

Answer (score 0):

put your

```
Icepick.restoreInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState);
```

in `onCreateView()` (instead of in `onCreate`)